# image created by httphandler is not shown in google chrome but it works only in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I am using Asp.Net ChartControl for Visualization. This control creates in memory image & that image is rendered as response from server to client.
Example path of image.

```
http://WebsiteName/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_d9a62d4ec93b4b479337b2a204957c75_1.png&g=4e7c77bc2c374858a9b8b387acabf650
```

This works fine in `IE` but it does not work in `Chrome` or `FireFox`.

Let me know if you need any details about my problem.

---

## Edit

- ***Merging comments***

> I created a user control

```
ChartEmbedControl embedControl = page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ChartEmbedControl.ascx") as ChartEmbedControl;
```

> Then i bind all required data to it & then converted it into html string like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb); 
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
embedControl.RenderControl(writer); 

// and then...
page.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

This is the response of one ajax call made from javascript. Response contains Image with given path(Path is mentioned in problem statement). Image is shown in IE but not in chrome

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, press F12, and see if there are any errors under 'console'. Or maybe other hints to what is wrong (from access denied to not found) 
If you want, post a public URL, I can look for you.

Comment: http://localhost:60261/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_d9a62d4ec93b4b479337b2a204957c75_1.png&g=ebebaa7f069b42cf9ad4d8755e72d89c Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The image is not found.)  This is the error in console

Comment: and if you go to that URL on localhost directly from chrome?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - The image is not found. This error is given

Comment: so the exact same URL works in IE but not in Chrome? Try to do Shift+F5 in Chrome? (reload without cache) Chrome is right of course, the axd file doesn't really exist, but IIS should take care of that.

Comment: I tried Shift+5 in chrome but still it does not work. you are right that IIS should take care of this. I am making this ajax call from non home html page(cross domain call) where it is not working. But when same call is made from same website page (i.e: one of the page from same website) it works in google chrome as well. But Response given is same in both the cases.

Comment: I am making an AJAX call from JavaScript for this graph Image. when i make AJAX call from the same website page at that time image is show by each browser which includes chrome also. but when same call is made from cross domain page then only IE shows the image , chrome does not show that image.

Comment: Sounds like a CORS problem, for which Chrome is a bit stricter. Try to run without security to see if that is the problem: something like this: Close Chrome, open terminal, type open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security (found @Seanonymous)

Comment: can you add this header to the site that returns the image?Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *